# Can't remove items (torrent files) from Folx that were failed to load

Tags: macos, macbook, osx-yosemite

Can't remove few items after the torrent files was not loaded. Most probably the files were corrupted. Have no clue at all. Btw I am running Folx 4.1.12414 on OSX Yosemite.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Folx failed to load items and cannot be removed.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. close Folx
2. remove ~/Library/Application Support/Eltima Software/Folx3/Folx3Data.storedata